# Getting error "TypeError: no numeric data to plot" in a Time Series ARIMA analysis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, arima

I am trying to follow a tutorial whereby an ARIMA time series analysis using *differenced data* is being done:

The following is the python code:

```
def difference(dataset):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]
        diff.append(value)
    return Series(diff)

series = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
X = series.values  # The error in building the list can be seen here
X = X.astype('float32')
stationary = difference(X)
stationary.index = series.index[1:]
...
stationary.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

When the process reaches the plotting stage I get the error:

> TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Tracing back, I find that the data that is being parsed is resulting in a collection of array. Saving the collection **stationary** as `*.csv` file gives me a list like:

```
[11.]
[0.]
[16.]
[45.]
[27.]
[-141.]
[46.]
```

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong here?

PS. I have exluded the parts of import of libraries

**Edit 1**

A section of the dataset is reproduced below:

```
Year,Obs
1994,21
1995,62
1996,56
1997,29
1998,38
1999,201
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To difference, just use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) or [`DataFrame.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Also, `Year` should be the index:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Year': np.arange(1994, 2000),
     'Obs': [21, 62, 56, 29, 38, 201]})

stationary = df.set_index('Year').diff()
ax = stationary.plot(legend=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Okay. Now what **I have done**:

Using `series = df.loc[:, "obs"]` (**as suggested by** @e-motta) was able to get the column values to the y-axis *correctly*.

And **as suggested by** @BigBen, assigned index to the df at `read_csv` using `index_col='Year'`. Rest of the codes remain same. And it's working.

I don't know under the circumstances which one to accept as the correct answer (*and how a situation like this is handled on SO*) , so I am upvoting both.

Comment: "How a situation like this is handled on SO": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267545/allow-accepting-multiple-answers. It's really up to you.

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar BigBen's answer is better overall. I'd accept his over mine.

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) returns a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), not a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

You can read the data as a `pandas.DataFrame`, then select the columns you want in each axis. The selected column are `pandas.Series`. Column `Year` is converted to `str` so it doesn't show as `float`.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
y = difference(df["Obs"])
x = df["Year"].astype(str)[1:]
pyplot.plot(x, y)
pyplot.show()
```

This will plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I dodn't clarify earlier in my post. Please note that the dataset is comprised of **two columns**, first column is for the *year* value (with `Year` as the header name) and the second column for the *observation* with numeric values (with `Obs` as the header name). If it helps I can add a section of the `*.csv` file's data.

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar Yes, please edit the question and include a sample of the data in the CSV.

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar If you only want to plot column `Obs`, you can replace the `iloc` with `loc`: `series = df.loc[:, "obs"]`

Comment: Thanks. I am checking this. In the meantime I have added part of the dataset in my post above. **Note** - Since I need to plot the data with `Year` as one of the variables I believe I would need to retain the colum.

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar Updated the answer. Consider the comment left by BigBen as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Tried `series = df.loc[:, "obs"]`. And the plot came out without error, **Thanks**. But as you would imagine, since the year column was not there, those values were missing from the plot (naturally). Trying to use `series = df.loc["Year", "obs"]` gets into error:  `KeyError: 'Year'` in the line : `series = df.loc["Year", "obs"]`.

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar Have you read my edited answer? Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Now I am getting error: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` **on line** `x = series["Year"].astype(str[1:])`...

Comment: @LovePutinNotWar Just copy what's in my answer. `astype(str)[1:]`, not `astype(str[1:])`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. But, now I am getting the plot where in the x-axis value (i.e. the `Year`) is all mangled (as if lots of values have been stuffed together). I was just thinking: In the code line in my post in lines `stationary = difference(X)`, the value *X* is being used in the `difference` computation for each `Obs` vs. `Year`. Could you please check with respect to that?